# slelnium python : clicking a dynamic object/element which has no id or name

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-inspector

when Right click is performed then an options popup/screen appears and its a dynamic content/element.

**This is the Options Popup:**

[image]

This dynamic content/element disappears as soon as the mouse is clicked somewhere else on the screen  even if its clicked on the inspect element window  the dynamic content/element disappears

there are few option to select from on the popup but in the html code there is not name or id to these options , so how can i access/select them from selenium using python ?

**This is How the HTML looks :**

[image]

i intend to select the option HMH NC by sending the Righ click using selenium and then making select the option but since there is no name or id for the options i can figure out how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to search for it by text.  I would do something like this (untested code):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By    

item_labels = WebDriverWait(my_driver,5).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.item span.label")),
    message="failed to find any menu items")

target = None
for item in item_labels:
    if item.get_attribute("text") == target_value:
        target = item
        break
target.click()
```

Comment: Beware that the "HMH NC" option is disabled in your images above!

Comment: Long time, how are you doing?

Comment: @BreaksSoftware yeah its disabled but it gets enabled depending on the conditions

Comment: @BreaksSoftware It seems to be giving an exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sam\Desktop\New folder (2)\sele - Copy (2).py", line 23, in <module>
    item_labels = WebDriverWait(browser,50).until(
  File "C:\Users\sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: failed to find any menu items

Comment: @Sam, this could indicate any of the following: The CSS_SELECTOR is bad (you can test it by searching for that string in the browser dev tools Elements tab), the menu items haven't been rendered (did the script click to open this menu?).  If you care to share the website url, and your source code, we might be able to help debug the problem.

Comment: [slight diversion...] hi @DebanjanB!  yeah, I've been busy implementing testing infrastructure at my new job...fun stuff, but it takes lots of work to get the basics in place.

Comment: @BreaksSoftware you are right ,sorry about my goofy mistake, i am still noob , the solution you provided works splendidly , it was the problem with loading the popup , the right click wasnt working properly hence there wasnt any element so it threw the exception , but after fixing the right click , your solution work like a charm